# Replacing text function value input on large txt file not work

Tags: text, vbscript, fso

The **expiration.txt** file contains **197.015** lines.

```
foo1; 2020-03-01 13:33;
foo2; 2020-02-01 08:45;
foo3; 2020-01-01 11:30;
...
...
...
```

On this large txt file I need replaced the all date value from:

1. **2020-03-01 13:33** to **2020-03-01**
2. **2020-02-01 08:45** to **2020-02-01**
3. **2020-01-01 11:30** to **2020-01-01**
4. ...
5. ...
6. **2018-01-01 12:40** to **2018-01-01** ( this is the last line number **197.015** )

I have tried the code below.

Don't have error but the replace input in txt file not work.

The new **expiration.txt** file remained unchanged.

How to do resolve this ?

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
intCount = 0
intIndex = 1
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
str_input = ""
Set oInFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("expiration.txt", 1)
str_input = oInFile.ReadAll()
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With oRegEx
    .Multiline = True
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+);"
End With
Do Until oInFile.AtEndOfStream
str_input = oInFile.ReadLine
If (intCount = 0) Then
   str_input = oRegEx.Replace(str_input, "$1-$2-$3;")
   Set oInFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("expiration.txt", 2)
   oInFile.Write str_input
   oInFile.Close
End If
intCount = intCount + 1
If (intCount = 200) Then
    intCount = 0
    intIndex = intIndex + 1
    oInFile.Close
End If
Loop
oInFile.Close
set oFSO = nothing
WScript.echo "ok"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading each line from the large input file, process the row, then write it to a new output file one row at a time.  If necessary, you can delete the original input file, and rename the new output file at the end of your script (after verification).

Some issues I see with your current script:

- It's calling both `ReadAll()` and `ReadLine()`, which is unnecessary.
- It's not calling `Close` for the original `ForReading` file handle prior to opening the same file again `ForWriting`.
- It only tries to translate the first row of the input file (and every subsequent 200th row), when `intCount` is 0 (zero).
- The regular expression is expecting seconds to be listed, but your example `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm;` date time data does not contain seconds, so the regular expression doesn't match.

I'm uncertain what the purpose of the `intCount = 200` block was doing, so I have ommitted it from my answer.  Regardless, I kept the row counter `intCount` variable intact, just in case you want to use it later.

Here's a possible fix...

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1

Dim oRegEx : Set oRegEx = New RegExp
oRegEx.Multiline = True
oRegEx.Global = True
oRegEx.Pattern = "(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+);"

Dim intCount : intCount = 0
Dim str_input : str_input = ""
Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oInFile : Set oInFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("expiration.txt", ForReading)
Dim oOutFile : Set oOutFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("expiration~2.txt", True)
Do Until oInFile.AtEndOfStream
    str_input = oInFile.ReadLine()

    If oRegEx.Test(str_input) Then
        oOutFile.WriteLine oRegEx.Replace(str_input, "$1-$2-$3;")
    Else
        oOutFile.WriteLine str_input
    End If

    intCount = intCount + 1
Loop

oOutFile.Close
oInFile.Close

Set oOutFile = Nothing
Set oInFile = Nothing

' If necessary, use oFSO to delete the original expiration.txt file here, and rename expiration~2.txt to expiration.txt

Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oRegEx = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Ok"
```

Hope this helps.